# PowerShell Get-Content trim line

Tags: powershell

I'm a bit of a PowerShell rookie. I'm trying to parse an XML and store the attribute value in a variable. The goal is to be able to take the values between  the  blocks and store in the var. I can do it, but I'm storing the entire line. I don't know how to trim it to just the value.

XML Format snippet

> ```
> <Processors>
>   <Processor>
>     <Manufacturer>Intel(R) Corporation</Manufacturer>
>     <Version>Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 v3 @ 1.90GHz</Version>
>     <Speed>1900MHz</Speed>
>   </Processor>
>   <Number>1</Number>
> ```

```
$var = (Get-Content) discovery.xml | Where-Object {$_.Contains('Version')}
```

This will work but as I mentioned, the var looks like this

> ```
> <Version>Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 v3 @ 1.90GHz</Version>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
(gc discovery.xml | Where-Object {$_.Contains('Version')} | % { $_
-split { $_ -eq '<' -or $_ -eq '>'  } })[2]
```

Alternative:

```
Get-Content | Select-String -Pattern "<Version>(.*)</Version>" | select -ExpandProperty Matches | Select
-ExpandProperty Groups | Select -Expand Value -Last 1
```

Or:

```
(gc dicovery.xml -Raw | Select-Xml -XPath "/Processors/Processor/Version/text()[1]").Node.Value
```

Comment: That put me on the right track. Working now, thanks mate.

Comment: My last answer is most likely the best way, I had to look up the XPath syntax though :)

Comment: `Select-Xml` have `-Path` parameter. You do not have to use `Get-Content` separately.